# Using ack to effectively search and RStudio project directory

Tags: grep, search, r, ack, rstudio

I'm interested in running `ack` search on a [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com) project directory that mostly contains `*.R` script files but also some project files and often `*.git` files.

## Directory

The project folder structure created from a default [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com) application:

```
$ tree
.
├── SomeNosense.Rproj
├── server.R
└── ui.R
```

## Search

Given this I'm interested in running a simple search for a word ***old*** across the **`*.R`** files only. *The sample shiny app created as a defult projects has some strings where the word **old** is mentioned*.

```
ack -i -rr 'Old'
```

I'm getting results that do not match what should correspond to `ack --help-types`, which shows:

```
--[no]rr           .R
```

### Results

whereas 
 my results for this command are very messy:

```
.Rproj.user/38B87E11/sdb/s-FEC4716C/28624A5C
7:    "folds" : "",

.Rproj.user/38B87E11/sdb/s-FEC4716C/8A580C19
3:    "contents" : "\n# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application.\n# You can find out more about building applications with Shiny here:\n#\n# http://shiny.rstudio.com\n#\n\nlibrary(shiny)\n\nshinyUI(fluidPage(\n\n  # Application title\n  titlePanel(\"Old Faithful Geyser Data\"),\n\n  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins\n  sidebarLayout(\n    sidebarPanel(\n      sliderInput(\"bins\",\n                  \"Number of bins:\",\n                  min = 1,\n                  max = 50,\n                  value = 30)\n    ),\n\n    # Show a plot of the generated distribution\n    mainPanel(\n      plotOutput(\"distPlot\")\n    )\n  )\n))\n",
7:    "folds" : "",

ui.R
13:  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
```

## Desired results

Desired results can be achieved with `grep`:

```
me-547/47:SomeNosense$ grep -r -i 'old' ~/Documents/SomeNosense/*.R
/Users/me/Documents/SomeNosense/ui.R:  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
```

## Question

What is wrong with my [ack](/questions/tagged/ack) command that I'm not getting the same results?

---

The [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) also seems to be returning more accurate results:

```
me-552/52:SomeNosense$ ag -rr -i 'old'
ui.R
13:  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
me-553/53:SomeNosense$ ack -rr -i 'old'
.Rproj.user/38B87E11/sdb/per/t/28624A5C
7:    "folds" : "",

.Rproj.user/38B87E11/sdb/per/t/8A580C19
3:    "contents" : "\n# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application.\n# You can find out more about building applications with Shiny here:\n#\n# http://shiny.rstudio.com\n#\n\nlibrary(shiny)\n\nshinyUI(fluidPage(\n\n  # Application title\n  titlePanel(\"Old Faithful Geyser Data\"),\n\n  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins\n  sidebarLayout(\n    sidebarPanel(\n      sliderInput(\"bins\",\n                  \"Number of bins:\",\n                  min = 1,\n                  max = 50,\n                  value = 30)\n    ),\n\n    # Show a plot of the generated distribution\n    mainPanel(\n      plotOutput(\"distPlot\")\n    )\n  )\n))\n",
7:    "folds" : "",

ui.R
13:  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
```

RStudio: 1.0.143

Comment: Try `ack` with `--rr` (two dashes).  `-rr` (one dash) means `-r -r`, which is essentially useless.

Comment: Same problem with `ag`: `ag --r` (two dashes, single `r`), rather than `ag -rr` (one dash, double `r`).

Comment: I'm the author of ack, and that `-rr` vs. `--rr` confusion is eye-opening.  I'm trying to figure where I could put a mention of that somewhere in the docs.  Thanks for answering, @SatoKatsura.

Comment: @AndyLester I'd say the natural candidate would be output of `ack --help-types`.  One definitely has to read that to find out the exact incantation for language X. :)